# ColdFusion 10 multi-instance on development install

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

So I am using ColdFusion 10 on Windows 7 64-bit machine. I have installed CF10 developer edition, now I am trying to create a second instance. I Add the instance in ColdFusion admin, then go into the Number folder and run the webconfig tool and add the site. When I go to services to start this new instance service, it does not start, it gives me an error.

App log:

> The description for Event ID 256 from source ColdFusion 10 Application Server perm cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

Can anyone help me get the second instance working, or is this really not allowed in the dev edition?

If I can get this working for ColdFusion 10, I want to get ColdFusion 11 working with 2 instances next.

Comment: seems like I got the server running, it might have been because I followed http://rob.brooks-bilson.com/index.cfm/2012/2/23/Configuring-Multiple-Instances-of-ColdFusion-10-with-Apache-Virtual-Hosts   at least some of the steps. Then i got an isapi/cgi error, i figured out that error, now i have the dreaded 500 error..isapiModule. I know I am close.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work with the adobe install team, and they helped me figure out my web config connectors were messed up, and there was a random cfide folder in the site causing confusion and delay. I am up and running now.